# Existence of unique homomorphism between free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups, universal-property

We know that a free group F(S) on a set S comes equipped with a function
$\alpha_S : S \to F(S)$. For any function $\beta: S \to G$, for some
group $G$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\phi : F(S) \to G$ such that
$\phi \circ \alpha_S = \beta$.

Suppose that $f : S \to T$ is a function between sets $S$, $T$. Show
that there exists a unique homomorphism between free groups
$F(f) : F(S) \to F(T)$ such that $F(f) \circ \alpha_S = \alpha_T \circ f$.

I do not see how $F(f)$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

$F(f)$ is the unique morphism induced by the map $\alpha_T \circ f:S \to F(T)$. By definition of the universal property you mentioned, this morphism is a group homomorphism.